# Can I travel by air to Canada from Mexico with only a US birth certificate?

Tags: air-travel, canada, paperwork, us-citizens, mexico

I'm an American citizen in Mexico and I want to fly to Canada. The only thing is that I only have my American Birth Certificate! I do not have any other ID.

Canada says that American Citizens can enter by land with a Birth Certificate. However I could not find out anything about entering by air with only a Birth Certificate.

Comment: Do you have any form of photographic ID? A driver's license, a military ID, etc.?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that without a passport or at least some sort of photo ID, you will not be allowed to board any flight whatsoever in Mexico.  I think your best bet is to get in touch with the nearest US consulate and start the process for getting a passport.

Comment: According to your question, you have no ID at all.  A birth certificate is not identification.  It may prove that Jose Martinez is a USA citizen permitted to enter Canada... but it doesn't prove that *you* are Jose Martinez.

Answer (score 3):

According to TIMATIC, the database used by airlines to decide whether a passenger's documents are sufficient, you can indeed use a birth certificate to prove your US citizenship when arriving by air, but as noted in a comment, you will probably have to identify yourself with a photo ID before being allowed to board the plane in Mexico.  The TIMATIC text:

> Passport Exemptions:
>   Nationals of the USA with a recommended proof of citizenship such as a:
>   - US birth certificate; or
>   - US certificate of citizenship; or
>   - US certificate of naturalization; or
>   - US Consular Report of Birth Abroad.
>   Nationals of USA with a NEXUS Card embarking in USA or Canada and entering Canada from the USA or US territories .
>   Nationals of USA with an emergency passport.
>   Document Validity:
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay.
>   Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure document is required by the US immigration authorities.
>   Additional Information:
>   Holders of proof of citizenship issued by USA not holding a valid passport; will be granted entry upon arrival only after examination by a Canadian Border Services Officer if having satisfied the officer about their citizenship.

Given the uncertainty expressed in the last paragraph, I suspect that even if you had a photo ID such as a driver's license, the airline would not let you board.

Comment: Your last sentence is important - even though birth certificate etc. may be approved for entry, the _airline_ may not be satisfied there is enough to prove citizenship and not allow the passenger to board the plane (and therefore not given a chance to even try it with the border services officer)

Comment: To enter Mexico a passport would be needed.

Comment: @hecvd the question describes a US citizen who is already in Mexico and not in possession of  a passport.  There are several possible ways for that situation to arise, but without knowing how it arose, it's hard to say more about it.  (Furthermore, it seems to be possible for a US citizen to enter Mexico without a passport if the US citizen enters by land and remains within 20 km of the border.)